# Why doesn't the Scala List have a size field?

Tags: java, list, scala, data-structures

Coming from a Java background, I'm wondering why `List` in Scala doesn't have a `size` field like its Java equivalent `LinkedList`. After all, with a size field you'll be able to determine the size of the list in constant-time, so why was the size field dropped?

(This question refers to the new collection classes in Scala 2.8 and later. Also, I'm referring to the immutable `List`, not the mutable one.)

Comment: It's `size()` in Java, a function.

Comment: But the function is backed by a field, which makes it O(1). Scala List has no such field, for good reason, but that makes accessing the length O(n).

Comment: "*python* dude" comes from a *Java* background? *python* doesn't refer to the language, does it?

Comment: @huynhjl: Am I not allowed to have more than one background? ;-)

Comment: @huynhjl: No. It means he's a male python.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One cannot say the size field was *dropped*, as such list without the size have existed for 50 years since LISP where they are ubiquitous and they are very common in ML and Haskell too, both influential in scala.

The basic reason is that list is a recursive structure. A non empty `List` is `Cons(head: A, tail: List[A])` — except that [Cons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons) is in fact called `::` to allow a convenient infix notation. You can access the tail (the list without its head element) and that is a list too. And this is done just about all the time.  So having the count in the list would not mean adding just one integer, but as many integers as there are elements. This is feasible, but certainly not free.

If you compare with java's `LinkedList`, `LinkedList` has a recursive implementation (based on Node, which is more or less like Cons, but with links in both direction). But a LinkedList is not a Node, it owns them (and keep their count). So while it has a recursive implementation, you cannot treat it recursively. It you wanted the tail of a LinkedList as a LinkedList, you would have to either remove the head and have your list changed or else copy all the tail elements to a new LinkedList. So scala's `List` and java's `LinkedList` are very different structures.

Comment: Lists are strict in scala. So every time Cons applied it knows size of the tail and so can increase by 1 and write it to a specific field. Like `Cons(head : A, tail : List[A]) { override val size : Int = tail.size + 1}`. It is possible, but may be considered too space hungry.

Answer (score 12):

Because maintaining this field would

1. Add memory overhead to all lists;
2. Add slight time overhead on every list creation.

In Java normally a `LinkedList` is created, and then manipulated without creating new lists by adding/removing elements; in Scala there are many `List`s created.

So it was decided that the overhead isn't worth it.

Comment: In fact, adding a `size` field would *double* the size of a _cons_ from 8 to 16 bytes, given that objects are allocated in multiples of 8 bytes.

Answer (score 10):

The "disadvantage" of O(n) complexity is not as big as you might think. Martin Odersky mentioned in a talk that (if I remember correctly) 90% of all lists created in all programs in any computer language have a size of 4 or less. (This was in the context of immutability and efficiency)

Therefore, O(n) access time for `size` is not such a big overhead for most lists created, and, as others have mentioned here, memory savings more than compensates for this.

Answer (score 8):

List defines size :

```
> List(1, 2, 3).size
res4: Int = 3
```

which has linear o(n) execution time. If you really need a constant time, you should consider the mutable `ListBuffer` that provides a constant time size implementation.

Comment: Which version of Scala is this? Before or after 2.8?

Comment: at least since 2.8 and later. See : http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.8.0/scala/collection/immutable/List.html

Comment: Is this constant-time though? it says "equivalent of length"

Comment: In fact your are right. List has linear o(n) size execution time has we can see on the code : https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_0_1/src//library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L1

Comment: FWIW immutable `Vector` is an indexed data structure with efficient `length` (among other indexed operations)—so there are alternatives to sacrificing immutability if you have no other good reason to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked the [length](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.7/scala/List.html#length) field?

Comment: `length` is a method thst traverses the whole list, hence having `O(n)` complexity. The OP asks why there is no `length` *field* with constant time access.

Comment: @Udo Held: Your link is from Scala 2.7.7, which I have no experience with. My question is based on Scala 2.9+, and specifically on the book "Programming in Scala", 2nd Ed., where it's stated in chapter 16 that determining the length of a List is linear in the number of elements.

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/LinkedList.html has the length as well and is 2.9. You will find size there as well which is equivalent to length.

Comment: I think the question referred to the immutable List, which is the default one in scala. It has no length field

Answer (score 0):

am I missing something? The size is there:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_29).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import scala.collection.immutable.List
import scala.collection.immutable.List

scala> val a = List(1,2,3)
a: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> a size
res0: Int = 3
```

Comment: exact but it's a o(n) size implementation. The subject was that LinkedList java implementation have a size field that returs the size in constant time.