# Recursive collections in Scala such as List

Tags: scala, collections, recursive-datastructures

The aim is to use a Scala collection where the size needs not be computed iteratively or recursively.

For instance `List` proves to be a recursive construction (consider for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/8197826/3189923), and in order to obtain the size it is necessary to iterate over it; namely an `O(N)` operation on the number of elements in the list.

Thus to ask for which collections this operation is `O(1)` ?
Many Thanks.

Comment: I recently found a talk by Daniel Spiewak, he spoke about functional data structures in scala. Here is a link http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Functional-Data-Structures-in-Scala Maybe you can extract the knowledge you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cost of method `size` for main immutable collections (according to quick view on code):

```
Seq:
  LinearSeq:
    List - O(N)
    Stream - O(N)*
    Queue - O(N) // Implemented using List
    Stack - O(N)* // Implemented using List, with additional complexity
  IndexedSeq:
    Vector - O(1)
    NumericRange - O(1)
    Array - O(1) // WrappedArray, ArrayOps
    String - O(1) // WrappedString, StringOps
    Range - O(1)
Set:
  HashSet - O(1) // HashSet.HashTrieSet
  TreeSet - O(N) // RedBlackTree.count - recursive with stack usage 
  BitSet - O(Max)* // fast enough. O(1) for collections of small ints
  ListSet - O(N)
Map:
  HashMap - O(1) // HashMap.HashTrieMap
  TreeMap - O(N) // RedBlackTree.count - recursive with stack usage
  ListMap - O(N)
```

#### Stream

From documentation:

> In order to compute the length of the `Stream`, it must first be fully realized, which could cause the complete evaluation of an infinite series, assuming that's what your `Stream` represents.

#### Stack

`Stack#length` complexity is much worse than `List#length` complexity: it creates `N` new objects to iterate over `Stack`.

#### BitSet

`BitSet` is for collections of small integers.

Complexity of `BitSet#size` depends on maximal element, not on count of elements. It's about `O(Max/64)`. See also [BitSet#size implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/BitSetLike.scala#L63).

#### TreeSet/TreeMap

I'm not sure about `TreeSet` and `TreeMap` complexity, it looks like recursive with stack usage (not tail recursive). See [RedBlackTree.count implementation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/RedBlackTree.scala#L392).

Answer (score 1):

- For the immutable collections, `Vector` has a constant `size` operation
- The mutable `Array` has constant a `size` operation
- For the mutable collections, both `ListBuffer` and `ArrayBuffer` have constant `size` operations.