# Find bottleneck in Scala merge algorithm

Tags: performance, algorithm, scala

I am learning Scala and as a starting point I am trying to write a mergeSort algorithm. I am having problem with the performance of the merge part of it.

I know that there are other implementations on this site but I would like to know why my one is not working well.

This is my code:

```
@tailrec
    def merge(l1:List[Int], l2:List[Int], acc:List[Int]): List[Int] = {

      if(l1.isEmpty || l2.isEmpty) l1 ++ l2 ++ acc
      else if(l1.last> l2.last) merge(l1.init, l2, l1.last :: acc)
      else  merge(l1, l2.init, l2.last :: acc)
    }

    val a1 = List(1,4,65,52151) 
    val a2 = List(2,52,124,5251,124125125)

    println(merge(a1, a2, List()))
```

How can you see the merge function is tail recursive and (if I am not wrong) the list methods that I am using should take constant time.

The code gets very slow with a list of 100000 elements.

Comment: As Didier points out, when using `List`s you want to use them as a stack, i.e. using `head` and `tail`.  You might want to try using `Vector`s instead as an exercise, to see the performance difference.  Of course, for code critical to performance you would likely use `Array`s instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`last` and `init` are terribly expensive on List:  O(N). The efficient operations are `head` and `tail`: O(1). If you can't work at the start, reverse the lists up front (O(N) but just once, not at each iteration), or reverse your output at the end, but you need to work at the beginning of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find bottlenecks is with a profiler. I understand netbeans has a free one; if you can get jprofiler or yourkit they're very nice to use. In this specific case I'd point out that `last` and `init` are O(n), because `List` is a (singly) linked list.

Comment: How can I know the complexity of the default methods? Is there an official? reference for them

Comment: @Donbeo you should be able to figure it out for yourself. You need to study algorithms and basic data structures. Look into learning about Big-O notation

Comment: I am familiar with these stuff but I thought that sometimes the standard implementation inside of some methods can have particular effects. For example I thought that the pointer to the last element of the list was stored inside the list object while apparently this is not true

Comment: The scala API docs are clear in this case. For List, under "Performance": "Time: List has O(1) prepend and head/tail access. Most other operations are O(n) on the number of elements in the list. This includes the index-based lookup of elements, length, append and reverse." (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.immutable.List)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8197826/754787 : Here is an old answer of mine on why List does not keep its count, and the same reason works for not keeping last.